# How do I use the browser's confirm() along with an Angular template statement?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to do this:

```
<button (click)="confirm('some message') ? someFunction() : anotherFunction()">Text</button>
```

This of course fails, because Angular looks for the confirm() function within its own code. It fails compilation with an error statement like so:

```
ERROR in src\client\pages\x.component.html(72,114): : Property 'confirm' does not exist on type 'OurCustomComponent'.
```

Is there a way to make this work? I do realize (having just read the documentation now), that some javascript syntax is disallowed, but it's unclear if there's a way to accomplish this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a wrapper function in the component.

```js
confirm(): void {
  confirm('some message') ? this.someFunction() : this.anotherFunction();
}
```

```html
<button (click)="confirm()">Text</button>
```